# Why would my code be an appropriate style for Java, but not for Python

Tags: python

Why would my code be an appropriate style for Java, but not for Python?

```
dct=getDictionary()
if dct.has_key(3):
    invokeTriples(dct[3])
    postProcessForTriples()
    print("Done for triples")

if dct.has_key(7):
    invokeSeptuples(dct[7])
    postProcessForOthers()
    print("All done!")
```

Personally, I don't see the problem. Can you explain what she meant by 'appropriate'? And maybe give me a good idea of the approach I should take to making it more appropriate?

Comment: Maybe the variable naming convention? In Python, usually people prefer writing `get_dictionary()`, `invoke_triples`, (and so on) instead. Maybe you would like to visit https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated in Python 2 and gone in Python 3. Use `in`.

Answer (score 0):

python is entirely based on indentation so your if statements being indented is wrong (since they don't need to be)

You also have your dct indented by 1, your if 3 more and then your internals of if statement 4 more so your indentation is not consistent.

Finally your statement is pretty ambiguous since your code isn't actually styled for java.

here is how your  code should probably be formatted

```
dct=getDictionary()
if dct.has_key(3):
    invokeTriples(dct[3])
    postProcessForTriples()
    print("Done for triples")
if dct.has_key(7):
    invokeSeptuples(dct[7])
    postProcessForOthers()
    print("All done!")
```

Haven't used python for like 4 years so might be wrong but pretty sure that's how it works

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to say exactly what the commenter might be referring to, but a few things stand out even without context:

1. The names don't follow standard Python conventions (e.g. `snake_case`)
2. Indentation is wonky (this would cause a runtime error in Python because indentation matters)
3. `has_key` is deprecated; I don't think I've ever seen it used in actual Python code.

A more "pythonic" version of this code might look like:

```
dct = get_dictionary()
if 3 in dct:
    invoke_triples(dct[3])
    post_process_triples()
    print("Done for triples")
if 7 in dct:
    invoke_septuples(dct[7])
    post_process_others()
    print("All done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exact question is, "Why would my code be an **appropriate style** for Java, but not for **Python**?"

So, if I as an instructor gave you that comment, I would mean that you have not complied with [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). And, as your instructor that is an expectation I have of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is basically asking you to compare Java and Python. Since I am more experienced with java, I can tell you that you should compare the external libraries you used and calling `if` statement method.
If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.
I can't help you much because your question is generic 
Have a good day!